# Magento, Shop BY Block blowing out footer

Tags: magento, e-commerce, block, categories

Weve got our shop by block to display while browsing via a category.

It is displaying Category, Brand, Price.

The problem lies in the sheer number of brands is extending the box right out the bottom of the footer to accomdate all of the brands.

The owners do not want it to stop displaying category, brand, or price.

Any suggestions on how to either make the block have a scroll or have the block coordinate with the main cms to extend the footer to the bottom. 
or any other suggestions are welcome!

here is an example

http://growershouse.com/nutrients

Comment: I think, it should change in Magento admin panel under Catalog Menu. Then, go to sub menu Manage Category. You will see display setting in this menu. I'm not pretty sure this will help or not. Basically, all category display setting is change in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that by little bit of jQuery, by the way your site html is aweful :P

```
var brandHeight = jQuery('#reviewremove .block-content').height();
 jQuery('#ghmain').height(brandHeight);
```

Comment: which of the 30 html pages would i put that jQuery? and ALL that html is generated by Magento. what does this bit of jquery do?

Comment: it will get the height of brand column(which is heighest) and add it to the main column which will push footer to its place but this code needs little more editing to make sure the brand column is heighest before executing this style. Try it

Answer (score 0):

I went with the easier option of modifying the div DIRECTLY for the catalog view.
and avoided unweildy jQueries that are like killing a fly with an anvil.

First I had to locate a file that is unfindable thanks to Magentos seriously unfriendly file system. I couldn't even figure out which file I would need to edit or which css. 
I downloaded an e-book called "Magento Template Cheat Guide" to locate the folder the "sshop by" block lives in.

/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml

```
<div class="block-content">
    <?php echo $this->getStateHtml() ?>
    <?php if ($this->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters()): ?>
```

to this

```
<div class="block-content" style="width:193px; height:920px; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;">
```

SIMPLE HTML ANSWER FOR AN HTML PROBLEM. not a jquery.